# Function for columns to inherit custom class of data frame in R

Tags: r, r-s3

I have a list of dataframes

```
dd <- list()
dd$dat <- list(
  one = data.frame(a = c(1), b = c(2)),
  two = data.frame(c = c(3), d = c(4)),
  three = data.frame(e = c(5), f = c(6))
)
```

and wrote a function to append a custom class to each dataframe:

```
# append classes 
append_classes <- function(x, nm) {
  class(x) <- 
    case_when(
      nm == "one" ~ c(class(x), "foo"),
      nm == "two" ~ c(class(x), "bar"),
      TRUE ~ c(class(x), "custom")
    )
  return(x)
}

dd$dat <- imap(dd$dat, append_classes)
```

```
class(dd$dat[[1]])
```

It works!

```
[1] "data.frame" "foo"
```

But now I want to use class inheritance to have the columns in each data frame inherit the `foo`, `bar`, and `custom` classes respectively - how would I do this?

## Desired Output

```
class(dd$dat$one$a)
```

```
[1] "numeric" "foo"
```

```
class(dd$dat$two$d)
```

```
[1] "numeric" "bar"
```

I'm very new to using S3 so any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `imap` recursively or use `map` inside

```
library(purrr)
dd$dat <-  imap(dd$dat, ~ {nm1 <- .y
       map_dfr(append_classes(.x, nm1), ~ append_classes(.x, nm1))
       })

class(dd$dat$one$a)
#[1] "numeric" "foo"    
class(dd$dat$two$d)
#[1] "numeric" "bar"
```

---

Or this can be done with `base R` using `Map/lapply`

```
dd$dat <- Map(function(x, y) {
     tmp <- append_classes(x, y)
    tmp[] <- lapply(tmp, append_classes, nm = y)
    tmp} , dd$dat, names(dd$dat))
class(dd$dat$one$a)
#[1] "numeric" "foo"
```

Comment: Thank you but I got the warning `In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  Vectorizing 'numeric' elements may not preserve their attributes` and running `class(dd$dat$two$d)` only resulting in numeric - am I missing something?

Comment: @MayaGans can you check my update.  Earlier, I made a mistake in understandding the attributes.

Comment: Thank you! The base R version works but the `purrr` version throws the warning `In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Vectorizing 'numeric' elements may not preserve their attributes` and interestingly it works when the vector is a character but if numeric it doesn't add the `foo` class do you know why this could be?

Comment: @MayaGans with tidyverse, each version there could be many changes and that may be an issue.  What is your package version for `purrr` and `dplyr`